# How can I override the default colors of Bootstrap in my Astro project?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5, astrojs

I have an Astro project. I have installed SCSS functionality. I have downloaded the bootstrap source files (Bootstrap 5.3.2) and have the full scss folder contents under src/bootstrap in my project.

At the base of my layout file, I have this:

```
<style lang="scss">
    @import "../bootstrap/functions";
    @import "../bootstrap/variables";

    $custom-colors: (
        "primary": #8630b8,
        // "secondary": ,
        // "success": ,
        // "info": ,
        // "warning": ,
        // "danger": ,
        // "light": ,
        // "dark": ,
    );

    // Merge Custom Colors
    $theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-colors);

    @import "../bootstrap/bootstrap";
</style>
```

This correctly adds Bootstrap styling, but the colors are not being overridden. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should not use `@import` anymore. It is officially not recommended and deprecated by SASS. Use `@use...with` syntax to override variables: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/#configuration

Comment: try moving overrides _between_ `functions` and `variables`: _Variable overrides must come after our functions are imported, but before the rest of the imports._ https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/#importing, also, you seem to be mixing two customization approaches.. check the linked BS customization guide

Comment: (Not to be confused with [astroturfing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358275/what-to-do-about-tag-that-appears-to-be-nothing-more-than-astroturfing).)

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you're using SCSS and trying to customize Bootstrap's theme colors by defining your custom colors using the $custom-colors map. The code you provided is on the right track. However, you need to ensure that you are correctly defining and importing Bootstrap's functions, variables, and main stylesheet.

Here's an example of how you can modify and organize your SCSS code for customizing Bootstrap's theme colors:

```
// Import Bootstrap functions and variables
  @import "../bootstrap/functions";
  @import "../bootstrap/variables";
    
    // Define your custom colors
$custom-colors: (
  "primary": #8630b8,
  // Add other custom colors if needed
);
    
// Merge custom colors with Bootstrap theme colors
    $theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-colors);
    
// Import Bootstrap main stylesheet
    @import "../bootstrap/bootstrap";
```

Make sure you have the correct paths for importing Bootstrap's functions, variables, and main stylesheet.

After making these changes, the custom colors should be applied to your Bootstrap components that use the theme colors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: What is the second revision? A new output from [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or simiar)?